# How do I create a messagebox to inform successful send of email n XPages?

Tags: xpages, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

My web page send and email after button is click. I need a messageBox after clicking the send button, the messagebox got display just normal text but if i add a variable value it wont work, any idea how i can go about these?

```
var Admin =  doc.getItemValueString("Admin");
var scriptCode= "alert('Email send to the admin:' + Admin )";
view.postScript(scriptCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code to look like this:

```
var scriptCode = "alert('Email send to the admin: " + Admin + "')";
```

Comment: how can i redirect to another page after the alert is display and the user click on ok, because when i try to use 'context.redirectToHome()' then the alert did not work again

Comment: Simon, I will suggest that you post another question on this.